# Keras Image Preprocessing .flow(x, y, save_to_dir) only saves the augmented x images and not the y's

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, data-augmentation

I am using `Keras data augmentation` for both my `x_train` and my `y_train` images for an image segmentation task.

For this I am using following code:

```
data_gen_args = dict(width_shift_range = 0.05)
aug = kp.image.ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)

history = model.fit_generator(aug.flow(x_train, y_train, save_to_dir = augment_save_dir),
steps_per_epoch = len(x_train) / 32, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), epochs=epochs, verbose=1)
```

But this only saves my augmented `x images` and not their `labels`. **How can I save both the images and their labels to visualize them?**

I have already tried the example on the `Keras Image preprocessing` page [Example of transforming images and masks together](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) without success.

I get the error `AttributeError: 'zip' object has no attribute 'shape'`.

The code:

```
image_datagen = kp.image.ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
mask_datagen = kp.image.ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)

image_generator = image_datagen.flow(x_train, save_to_dir = augment_save_dir)
mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow(y_train, save_to_dir = augment_save_dir)

train_generator = zip(image_generator, mask_generator)

history = model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=len(x_train) / 32, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), epochs=epochs,verbose=1)
```

Also, is there any way to increase the `data_augmentation` parameters during training?